# Smoothing factor in $n$-day exponentially weighted average

Tags: moving-average, exponential-smoothing

I have read online that if we want an $n$-day exponentially weighted average we use the formula

$$
\alpha = \frac{2}{n+1}
$$

My question is why is this the case?

Does this choice of factor turn out to make the weighting of the $n+1$, $n+2$ ... data points negligible?